# Skype4Py: getting the handle of the person you're sending a message to

Tags: python, skype4py

I'm making a little bot for skype using skype4py. The bot is attached to MY skype client, and what I want is for the bot to accept input from either myself, or whoever i'm chatting with and to output to the chat window from where the input came.

To do this I use sendMessage(msgtext, handle_of_person_im_chatting_with).

It's pretty easy to accomplish when I receive a command from the person i'm chatting with because the RECEIVED event comes with a 'fromHandle' property containing their username, so I can direct sendMessage to that handle. But I can't figure out for the life of me how I could get that userhandle from the SENT event.

Comment: This is not directly related, but we did a bot using Skype4Py and group chat ids https://github.com/opensourcehacker/sevabot

Answer (score 0):

put this at the top after the imports

```
def commands(Message, Status):
    if Status == 'RECEIVED' or (Status == 'SENT'):
        if Message.Body.startswith(".help"):
            cmd_help(Message)
```

then for it to have an output for when .help is used put this

```
def cmd_commandhere(Message):
    Message.Chat.SendMessage("Hello, " + Message.Sender.Handle)
    print "commandhere command received from: " + Message.Sender.Handle
```

then at the bottom put this

```
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
client = Skype4Py.client.Client(skype)
skype.OnMessageStatus = commands

Skype.Attach()

while True:
    raw_input('')
```